# php : Show the headers received from the browser

Tags: php

So when a browser makes a HTTP request to a server, it is in the form some headers (get/post, cookies, host, User Agent, etc..). Is there a way I can read and display them in a php script? And yes $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE are there alright. I was looking for the rest of header info. eg http://pgl.yoyo.org/http/browser-headers.php Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My favorite: http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php

> Fetches all HTTP request headers from the current request.

```
<?php
    $headers = apache_request_headers();

    foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
        echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

[get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) function is what you are looking for. As quoted

> [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)  — Fetches all the headers sent by the server in response
> to a HTTP request

Simple example:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';   
print_r(get_headers($url));
```

Outputs all the information the send by the server:

> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> [1] => Date: Sat, 29 May 2004 12:28:13 GMT
> [2] => Server: Apache/1.3.27 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)
> [3] => Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
> [4] => ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
> [5] => Accept-Ranges: bytes
> [6] => Content-Length: 438
> [7] => Connection: close
> [8] => Content-Type: text/html )
> ```

---

#### Update

TO receive the information that is send by browsers, they can be accessed from [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) super global variable. For example, the following snippet gives all the browser related information.

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Similarly,

- `REQUEST_METHOD` : gives the HTTP Request method such as GET, HEAD, Put, Post
- `HTTP_HOST`: gives the HOST information
- `HTTP_COOKIE`: gives the raw information about the Cookie header <sup>[[Source]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#98408)</sup>

Comment: Not sure, but I was looking for the other way round. This function displays what the server sends back, but not the browser sent in when it made the request. Please correct me if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `$_GET['requestName']`, `$_POST['requestName']` (or `$_REQUEST['requestName']` to get either a GET or POST) to get these.

Cookies are via `$_COOKIE['varName']`. You may also want to look into `$_SESSION[]` as well.

Comment: @roopunk You might want to re-phrase your question as future googlers will likely not be helped. Starx has the right answer you are looking for. I already +1'ed it.

Comment: yeah. i made the edit. but umm.. i was looking for the other way round. Not what the server sends back.. but what browser sends in for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Look into the $_POST, $_GET, and $_COOKIE superglobals. They are arrays that contain the header info.
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

Comment: No, I mean, headers apart from them, for eg all the info here: [http://pgl.yoyo.org/http/browser-headers.php](http://pgl.yoyo.org/http/browser-headers.php)

Comment: Look at @Starx's answer. I think it has what you want.